# No network connection to virtual machine after connecting to VPN in host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

so I've downloaded the VPN windscribe and installed it everything works fine. My need is that I want my virtual machine to be on the same connection/VPN. For example when I connect to my vpn that means it's IP should change too; Sadly it isn't the same for me.
I am using Virtualbox on Windows 10.

Guest Machine: Kali Linux

Comment: Does your VPN allow split tunnel mode?  Try setting your Guest Machine to Bridged Network Mode.

Comment: Tried that. Still no connection sadly